# How to save image stream in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a imagestream in c# and i want to save them on the hard drive using the c# code. when i trying to do that i found Out of Memory whennever i have much enough Memory.

so i am sure that my code leak the resources so can someone show me how i can do that

```
HttpPostedFileBase file


 file.SaveAs(location);

 Image image = Image.FromFile(location,false);

 image.Save(location, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```

image.fromFile line [3] caused Exception that out of Memory. can someone show me how i can do this in c#.

The file come from PNG using Ajax Request are come as octet type as Mime type so how i can do that.

Comment: Mr. Spielberg, is there a reason you are saving it twice?

Comment: i guess he wants to convert all images into png format

Comment: i thing size of image is approx 2 MB @MARC

Comment: Are you sure that your image is really an image ?

Comment: because i need conversion to PNG and chrome put Mime type octet instead of png if file really image @ Bala

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you want to convert the image to PNG (otherwise there's no need to save the image once, reload it and re-save it again), it might be a good idea to avoid loading the image twice. See if something like this helps:

```
Image.FromStream(file.InputStream, false).Save(location, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```

Comment: Parameter is not valid. actually chrome put Mime type application/octet in ajax request even file are PNG

Answer (score 1):

```
file.SaveAs(location);
```

already saved the image at the given *location* or threw an exception, so the following lines are unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(file.InputStream);
        bmp.Save(filename, ImageFormat.Png);
```